# Adding fractions is not at all obvious

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $\frac{5}{4} + \frac{2}{3}$ need to be rewritten as  $\frac{15}{12} + \frac{8}{12}$ to be added? It's not obvious.

I'm looking towards the fact that any integer can be rewritten as $x=qy$ but these work for rational numbers as well.

Can anyone clarify why exactly fraction addition works only when you find a common denominator?

Comment: How would you simplify "$1$ miles + $1$ kilometer"? Since these are very different units, there's no easy way to combine them.

Fractions are similar: You can think of the fraction $p/q$ as measuring $p$ pieces of $1$ cut into $q$ pieces. In order to measure the total, we need comparable units first; the denominator can be though of as specifying what units one is using.

Comment: T.Bongers if you believe that my question is listed under arithmetic (and therefore answerable by any high school student), could you please answer my question?

Comment: One answer is that there's no reason to believe you should be able to add fractions without first finding a common denominator.  Students sometimes mistakenly try to add fractions by simply adding the numerators and also adding the denominators.  But simple examples show this gives the wrong answer.  For example, $\frac12 + \frac12 \neq \frac24.$

Comment: @user3200098 (I did answer, in a comment) If you disagree with my re-tagging the question, feel free to edit it again. Per the tag descriptions, however, the tags tag:abstract-algebra, tag:philosophy and tag:analysis are certainly not appropriate for the question.

Comment: @T.Bongers No, you deleted your answer. Besides, your answer was not even remotely related to the question.

Comment: I do believe analysis, abstract algebra and philosophy should be appropriate. Education and recreational are related on a personal level as I am wanting to understand this so that I can educate my students better (private tutoring high school children), so I was hoping for some input from teachers.

Comment: @user3200098 No, analysis and abstract algebra are entirely inappropriate as tags here because those terms have very specific meanings that do not apply to this question.

Comment: For the record, "abstract algebra" refers to the study of groups, rings, field, modules, etc. If you are familiar with the definitions of those, then this is the right tag for you. Analysis is essentially calculus, but made super-legit. This is unarguably an incorrect tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we have to define: what is a fraction? For now, we will just say it is an ordered pair $(a, b)$, where $b \ne 0$. We identify $(a, 1)$ with the integer $a$. (The notation doesn't matter, I just chose this so that we don't accidentally use identities we already know)

Here is what we want:

- $(a, 1) + (b, 1) = (a + b, 1)$
- $(a, 1)(b, 1) = (ab, 1)$
- $(a, 1)(1, b) = (a, b)$
- $(ac, bc) = (a, b)$
- Multiplication to distribute over addition.
- Multiplication and addition to be distributive and commutative.

This is sufficient to define everything! First, we show that $(a, 1)(1, a) = (1, 1)$:
$$(a, 1)(1, a) = (a, a) = (a1, a1) = (1, 1)$$
Next, we show $(1, a)(1, b) = (1, ab)$:
$$(ab, 1) \cdot (1, a) \cdot (1, b) = (ab, a) \cdot (1, b) = (b, 1) \cdot (1, b) = (1, 1)$$
Because $(ab, 1) \cdot \left( (1, a) \cdot (1, b) \right) = (1, 1)$, we know that $(1, a) \cdot (1, b) = (1, ab)$.

So now we want to find $(a, b) \cdot (c, d)$. We factor:
$$(a, 1) \cdot (1, b) \cdot (c, 1) \cdot (1, d) = (ac, 1) \cdot (1, bd) = (ac, bd)$$

Now we move on to addition:
$$ \begin{align*}
(a, b) + (c, d) &= (a, 1)(1, b) + (c, 1)(1, d) \\
&= (a, 1)(d, bd) + (c, 1)(b, bd) \\
&= (a, 1)(d, 1)(1, bd) + (c, 1)(b, 1)(1, bd) \\
&= (ad, 1)(1, bd) + (bc, 1)(1, bd) \\
&= [ (ad, 1) + (bc, 1) ] (1, bd) \\
&= (ad + bc, 1)(1, bd) \\
&= (ad + bc, bd)
\end{align*} $$

So, just starting from that bullet list, we have determined that $(a, b) + (c, d)$ *must* equal $(ad + bc, bd)$. If we change our notation, this gives us what you want.

Comment: In this approach, shouldn't a fraction be defined as a certain equivalence class of ordered pairs of integers?  Also, have the definitions of addition and multiplication of fractions been given here?

Comment: Yeah, formally it's $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \sim$, where $(a, b)\sim(c, d) \iff ad = bc$, but I don't think the OP is familiar with modding out by equivalence relations, given the misuse of the abstract-algebra tag.

Comment: As for the definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$, those were "constructed" in a way, from the bulleted list. Given those constraints, only one possible pair of operations exists.

Comment: This is the sort of answer I was looking for. Thank you. If not abstract algebra, what is this then?

Comment: This construction is taken from abstract algebra, yes, but unless you are comfortable with rings and fields, the general construction isn't exactly enlightening. I'm guessing your motivation for the question was "why do we define fraction addition this way?", and if so, then I would put it under algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, and definition.

Answer (score 8):

Think of the denominator as the units you're using to measure the fraction. $\frac{2}{3}$ is, literally, "two thirds", in the same way that $2$ cm is "two centimeters." The unit here is a third.

If you want to add two measures of distance, like "two meters plus fifteen decimeters", you have to find a common unit of measurement. In this case, you know that a meter is 100 centimeters, so two meters is 200 centimeters. You also know that a decimeter is 10 centimeters, so 15 decimeters is 150 centimeters. All in all you have 350 centimeters.

Same with fractions. If you want to add $\frac{5}{4} + \frac{2}{3}$, you have to find a common unit of measurement -- a bigger denominator that can be used to measure both fourths and thirds. There are many, and the best one is twelfths. Three twelfths is a fourth. Four twelfths is a third.

So, converting to this common unit of measurement, five fourths is fifteen twelfths and two thirds is eight twelfths. Now you have in total twenty-three twelfths, so
$$ \frac{5}{4} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{23}{12}.$$

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer after reviewing it a few times. (it's a lot more convoluted if you're European and don't work in inches).

Comment: @user3200098 Better? :)

Comment: Dear downvoter: Do you have any suggestions to improve my answer?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for *why* adding rational numbers *must* work this way, rather than looking for a natural motivation for this structure, here you go.

Assume the usual addition and multiplication methods and rules for integers, and the multiplication rules and distributive property for fractions.

Theorem: For $a, c$ any integers and $b, d$ nonzero integers,$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$

Proof: Suppose not. Then for some such $a, b, c, d$ defined as above, $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} \not = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$

This means  $$(bd)(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}) \not = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}(bd)$$

Applying distribution, we have that $$da+cb \not = ad+bc$$

a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

Write $x'$ for the reciprocal of $x$. Then from a purely algebraic standpoint, we have the following equations.

1. $\frac{5}{4}+\frac{2}{3} = 5 \cdot 4'+2\cdot 3'$
2. $\frac{15}{8}+\frac{12}{8} = 15 \cdot 8'+12\cdot 8'$

Observe that (2) is just the "common denominator" form of (1). Observe also that its easy to apply the distributive law to the RHS of (2); we see that the RHS equals

$(15+12) 8' = 27 \cdot 8' = 27/8$

On the other hand, there's no obvious way of applying the distributive law to the RHS of (1). So you might say: "We translate from form (1) into (2) in order to apply the distributive law."

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question which I feel was not celebrated enough at the time of posting. Anyways, here is how I'd do it. To begin with, you hopefully agree with me what the expression $\frac{a}{b}$ means conceptually: $a$ parts of $b$. Now, suppose we want to add $a$ parts of $b$ to $c$ parts of $d$, then one way to it is to size up everything by $bd$ then immediately size down by it. Why does this work?

$$ bd \cdot \frac{1}{bd}=1$$

So, we have:

$$  \frac{bd}{bd}  ( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}) = \frac{1}{bd} (  bd\frac{a}{b}+ bd \frac{c}{d})= \frac{ad+cb}{bd}$$

Second equality follows from distributivity of multiplication.