# Doubt about division between two polynomial: $x^2+10x+21$ and $x+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know $(x^2+10x+21)/(x+3)$ is $x+7$

But in $(x^2+10x+21)/(x+3)$ why can't we cancel $x^2$ with $x$ and $21$ with $3$ we get $x+10x+7$ what rule is breaking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're doing something like
$$\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\frac ac+\frac bd$$
for particular values of $a,b,c,d$.

Take $a=b=c=d$ to see that it isn't true in general.

Comment: Yeah right would you please explain in detail

Comment: @FrostFizz, I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677907/609343) has the desired detail. Please check the answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I will explain my answer in two steps:

**Step 1 - Proving $x+7$ is the correct answer:**

We can turn division into multiplication by

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+10x+21}{x+3}&=x+7\\
(x+3)(x+7)&=x^2+10x+21
\end{align}

We can expand the brackets

\begin{align}
&\quad(x+3)(x+7)\\
&=x\cdot x+x\cdot7+3\cdot x+3\cdot7\\
&=x^2+7x+3x+21\\
&=x^2+10x+21
\end{align}

Therefore, $x+7$ is the correct answer.

**Step 2 - Proving $x+10x+7=11x+7$ is not a correct answer:**

We can easily substitute this in, expand the brackets and get the wrong answer. To make this clearer, I have made an example where $x=10$. What you did was:

\begin{align}
&\quad\frac{10^2+10\cdot10+21}{1\cdot10+3}\\
&=\frac{10^2}{10}+10\cdot10+\frac{21}{3}
\end{align}

Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Yeah but x^2/x=x is right isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you cannot just separate a fraction like that.

Comment: Is this because of addition right because if there is multiplication we can by fraction rule

Comment: Yes, this is what the user Martund is saying. Sorry, I am going to sleep now, please expect me to respond to you tomorrow if you want to say more.

Answer (score 0):

You are interpreting letters and polynomial as numbers. But you can see them as function (in this case $x$).

So, you have to use polynomial division rule. There are two type of it: traditional division and Ruffini's law. Here you can use both and obtain:

$$(x^2+10x+21):(x+3)=x+7$$

And the remainder is $0$.